# CSS3 transition (background-color) refusing to work in Firefox

Tags: css, css-transitions

This is odd and I may be missing something blatant by my main navigation buttons on [build.advocatedaily.com](http://build.advocatedaily.com) have a CSS background color transition associated with them on hover.

It works in Chrome, but in FX it's just refusing to comply. Interestingly, when I open a submenu and hover off the element, the background color **reverts** to normal using a transition.

Thoughts?

Comment: why don't you post some of your code?

Comment: `.mainnav li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 3px 12px;
  border-right: 1px solid #990000;
  border-top: 1px solid #ca0002;
  border-left: 1px solid #ca0002;
  transition: background-color .4s;
  -moz-transition: background-color .4s; /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition: background-color .4s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition: background-color .4s; /* Opera */
}` I don't see any background color assigned.

Comment: try to create a demo at jsfiddle.net if you want to solve the problem. This is how stackoverflow works. Provide us some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove

```
position: relative;
```

from .mainnav li, worked here

firefox can be funny sometimes.

Comment: Some answers can be more funny.

Comment: Woah, I'm surprised that worked! 

Why would the positioning of the parent element affect a transition like that? How did you diagnose this?

Comment: @OrunBhuiyan im trying to replicate here, so far there isnt any kind of position conflict or anything like that, looks like ff bug on transitions

Comment: Odd, are you running OS X per chance?
I'll report to Mozilla shortly.

Comment: @OrunBhuiyan windows seven 64bits